# Angular routing returning to default page at all times

Tags: angular

I am fixing an old project full of surprises. One of them is the refresh after "signin".
It will go to redirect signin on '' (empty), upon signin success it will go to main. It actually does that for a microsecond for that to flash, then redirects to '' -> empty -> signin again.
I have been buggeling my head for a week looking for wrong routings and window.href =... (yes they use that some places). I can see no logic of it going to the signin page at all times.
Using href = "/main" it will stay on the main page, and "refreshing" does no longer happens.

The SigninGuard is working as it should.

Any ideas what to look at or what to try?

My routing:

```
  export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainPageComponent,
    canActivate: [SigninGuard],
    data: {
      title: 'Home page',
      subtitle: ''
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'signin',
    component: SigninComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Login',
      subtitle: ''
    }
  },  
  {
    path: 'report',
    component: ReportComponent,
    canActivate: [SigninGuard],
    data: {
      title: 'Status Report',
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'signin', // renaming this to signinHERE proved that it always goes here
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
    data: { title: '404' }
  }
];
```

The signin is basically:

```
 signIn(name, pass) {
    console.log("****** initiated");
    const credentials: IAccount = { UserName: name, UserPassword: pass };
      var result = this.loginService.login(credentials).subscribe(
result =>
{
  if(!result.ok) {
        window.location.href = '/signin2';
  } else {
     // save user name etc
       this.router.navigate([  '/home']);
  }
}
```

Comment: you do realize there's a `2` character, don't you? `window.location.href = '/signin2';`

Comment: @d pro: Yes used for testing. Just to see that it really will open. The issue is that on success it opens the main page for a second, then routes back to signin ('' in the routing - changing that so signin3 I see that it tries to go there).

Comment: I made it work, and created a new page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67990203/weird-behavior-of-angular-routing
I will delete this one by friday

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a breakpoint on the line:

```
if(!result.ok)
```

and check the value of result object returned from your subscription and if the property "ok" is defined within result. If it isn't defined then result.ok would return false.

You have also set the href to '/signin2', which isn't in your routing paths. Would using the router.navigate redirect to your sign-in page?

```
if(!result.ok) {
    this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
```

Comment: It works. The signin2 is for me to see that it goes somewhere else. I have a lot of console.log and alert in places and the signin procedure works as expected. It goes to the main page which flashes for a second, then goes to signin ( '' in the router, tested same way as signin2 here)

Comment: I made it work, and created a new page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67990203/weird-behavior-of-angular-routing
I will delete this one by friday

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue
It is related to refreshing when clicking a button and can be fixed by a simple return false; when the method/function is done

I found this issue described here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8537

The signin component, see last line

```
 signIn(name, pass) {
    console.log("****** initiated");
    const credentials: IAccount = { UserName: name, UserPassword: pass };
      var result = this.loginService.login(credentials).subscribe( result =>
   { // async code
     if(!result.ok) {
        // show error to user
     } else {
        // save user name etc
         this.router.navigate([  '/home']);
     }
   }); // end of async code   
  return false; // THIS line was needed
}
```